# Is ther a way to get the sizing of the image to show without distorting?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-bootstrap

Im using react-bootstrap for the carousel but I need the images to show without distorting the images. Please can someone assist me on this.

enter code here

function Slider() {
return (

```
<Carousel className="cont">
  <Carousel.Item interval={4000}>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src={bonsais4}
      alt="First slide"
    />
    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h1>Bonsai Den</h1>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item interval={4000}>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src={bonsais1}
      alt="Second slide"
    />
    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item interval={4000}>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src={bonsais3}
      alt="Third slide"
    />
    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
```

)
}

export default Slider

[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYqeF.png)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid distorting, you need to allow the image to maintain its aspect ratio when resize. You just need to add Bootstrap class

```
.img-fluid
```

Or if you like CSS:

```
img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```